# Why can´t my Docker mysql Container communicate with my nodejs backend Container?

Tags: mysql, docker-compose, dockerfile, containers

I cannot figure out why my mysql container cannot reach port 4306 of my nodejs backend container.
[image: Error:Connection refused on the mysql Container]

The Ports should be mapped to the right ones on the localhost.
[image: Docker-compose-file]

and the backend mysql database should connect to the right port on the container.
[image: Mysql-connection-in-backend].

[image: Frontend-Dockerfile]

[image: Backend-Dockerfile]

I am pretty new to Docker and the whole container and images stuff. I can reach the database on phpmyadmin on Port http://localhost:8098/ as I have mapped this port to Port 80 of the container. Also I can reach my frontend on port 3000(8080) and my backend on 3001(3001). I also tried to open the Port on the running mysql container with however even as root user of this container I don´t have permission. Here are also my frontend and backend Dockerfiles.

As I am not running any frontend-framework I installed http-server npm-package to host the frontend.
It worked for a while, I dont know why, but now I just get the connection refused error.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Add code and error messages as text not as image

Comment: Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-ot-upload-images-of-code-data-errors) to see how you can improve your question.

Comment: Thank you for the link, in my future questions I will not use images for my code and error-messages anymore :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You connect to `localhost:4306`, which is your backend container, not to the database container `db:4306`. If you change it, you should be able to access your db

Comment: Thank you Jens, it works now . In the future I will add code and error-messages as text. Sorry. Thank you for your answer it works now :), I guess I got confused from all the port-mapping.